# how to pass props to child in tsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

When I am passing props to the child I have a mistake "Property 'isClicked' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes"
I wrote "isClicked?: boolean". What more should I do?

```js
export interface DropDownProperties extends ComponentBaseProperties {
  multiSelect?: boolean;
  IconTextColor?:string;
  isClicked?: boolean;
}

export interface DropDownState extends ComponentBaseState {
  dropDownOptions: DropDownItem[];
  isOpen: boolean;
  results: string[];
  isClicked?: boolean;
 
}
export default class DropDown extends ComponentBase<
  DropDownProperties,
  DropDownState
> { return ( <DropDownItem
          iconName={option.iconName}
          value={option.value}
          displayValue={option.displayValue ? true : false}
          key={option.name}
          onClick={(e) => this.optionSelected()}
          isClicked={this.state.isOpen}
        >
          {option.props.children}
        </DropDownItem>
      ))}
       </ul>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your question seems to be not complete, can you please elaborate a bit on what is your question actually?

Comment: What's DropDownItem? In the code above `DropDown` was typed to have `isClicked` prop. Not `DropDownItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using connect in the component, using the below code should solve the problem.

```
export default connect<{}, {}, Props>(..........)
```

Here `connect` has 3 parameters, the third parameter is the interface `Props`, which has the variable you want to get the typing for.

Comment: There is the only way to do it with connect? I don't use it, there is no Redux in project

Comment: No it's not necessary to have redux.

Comment: since it's txs, define an interface with the prop isClicked in it. Extend the child component class with the Interface,like
class ComponentName extends React.Component<Props, any> {}
Add a constructor if necessary like
constructor(props, state) {
        super(props, state);
}
This should do the trick